# Comparing and putting in order Dominoes in C, with a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am really stucked and with a lot of doubts.

The question asks to verify possible possibilities and put in order n numbers of dominoes.

When I say "Order" it is not necessarily 12|23|34, this order is that basic rule of dominoes 51|12|23|36|62.

So, an accepted input is

3 // the number of dominoes
1 3 //
1 5 // possibilities
3 2 //
2 // the number of dominoes
3 4
2 5
0 // signals the end of dominoes

and an accepted output to this input would be

Test 1
yes
51|13|32|
Test 2
no
no

Below the basic scope, in C

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int NumOfDominoes = 1, Test = 1, Dominoes=1;
int E,D;
int boolean=1;

while( NumOfDominoes != 0 )
{
    scanf("%d",&NumOfDominoes);
    while( Dominoes < NumOfDominoes)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&E,&D);
        Insert( E, D); // the domino itself
        Dominoes++;
    }

}

for( Test ; Test <= NumOfDominoes ; Test++)
{
    printf("Test %d\n",Test);

    boolean = validity();  //returns 1 if the sequence of dominoes present equal values, i.e, possible possibilities

    if( boolean = 1) printf("yes\n");
    else {printf("no\nno\n");}

        masterFunction( E, D); //put in order the dominoes in order, 01|13|35...
}
return 0;
}
```

How can you see is missing three "small" functions, `Insert()`, `validity()` and `masterFunction(E,D)`.

Here is where I stucked, I don't know how to compare this dominoes, put in order and how to insert correctly. I don't know anything... :(

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is known as a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), which is typically implemented using recursion.

Choose a starting domino (in either of two orientations). That limits the choices and orientations for the second domino in the chain. Continue adding dominoes until either there are no valid choices for the next domino, or all of the dominoes have been added.

If all of the dominoes have been added, then you're done and the answer is "yes".

If you've tried every possible starting domino with all the possible subsequent dominos, and no chain uses all the dominoes, then the answer is "no".